# How can I operate on a particular column?

Tags: r

I know how to do it manually. But I would like to do it in a smart way. I am very confused how to use the apply functions.

All I want to do is sum the values of frequency column and divide every number by this sum. Also,I have to do this for a large number of data frames.

```
class Frequency
A  1
B  1
C  1
D  1
E  1
F  1
G  1
H  1
I  1
J  1
```

Expected output since Sum = 10.

```
class Frequency
A  .1
B  .1
C  .1
D  .1
E  .1
F  .1
G  .1
H  .1
I  .1
J  .1
```

Also, I have 10 such dataframes, say df1,df2,....,df10.

Comment: Are your data.frames stored in a list? (If not, they probably should be.)

Comment: You mean like this? mydata <- list(df1,df2,...,df10). I can make one.

Comment: And check out `mget` for that purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sample data frames in a list like this

```
mydata<-replicate(2, data.frame(
    class=letters[1:5], 
    Frequency=rpois(5, 4)), 
simplify=FALSE)
```

You can use an lapply to iterate over the list of data.frames

```
lapply(mydata, function(x) transform(x, Frequency=Frequency/sum(Frequency)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a general question. When I store this in x, my original dataframes are no longer getting updated, but now I have a new list x where I am able to access the frames by x[1],x[2] etc. So from now, if I have to add another operation to this, I access x[1]$frequency? Is this the suggested way of doing this instead of working with dozens of separate dataframes? I am working very crudely it seems.

Comment: Yes. If the data is somewhat related, life is much easier if you store the data.frames in a list rather than a bunch of separate variables. Often operations such as importing the data into a list can be easily factorized.

Comment: Also, what if I want my original dataframes to be updated separately instead of inside a list? Sorry, if I'm asking basic questions. How would I modify this lapply?